# SSH fails: "PTY allocation request failed", shell "not found"

Tags: ssh, docker, gitlab

I have GitLab CE running in Docker.
After upgrading GitLab CE to version 13.5.3, its SSH stopped working. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Executing `ssh git@<myhost>` results in

```
PTY allocation request failed
sh: 1: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell: not found
```

I have looked up the file in the Docker container and it exists.

I have already tried rebuilding the authorized_keys file and run a self-check
in accordance to https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html
and update file permissions as described at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#troubleshooting

```
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:check
docker exec gitlab update-permissions
docker restart gitlab
```

The self-check succeeded, but after all, the SSH problem persists. Has someone got an idea why the shell might be "not found"?

Comment: gitlab-shell is not an interactive shell, so you can't log in the container using that shell. Nevertheless, check the permissions of the file and its path are the right ones.

Comment: @JesúsÁngel you’re right, gitlab-shell is not interactive. However, you can establish an SSH connection irrespective of the shell.
The reason why I included that command and the error message is that the latter conains less unnecessary information than the git tools using SSH.
The expected output of the command would be:
`PTY allocation request failed
Welcome to GitLab, @<user>!`

Comment: @JesúsÁngel Thx, the permissions should suffice, I suppose. The directories within the path (/, /opt/, …, /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/) as well as the file itself are 755.